# Date of Easter in Java and UML Method Syntax

Tags: java, class, date, methods, uml

I wrote a class named Easter (see below) and a tester class named EasterTester (also below that) to execute it and plug in year values. The goal is implementing Gauss's algorithm for calc'n the month and day of Easter Sunday for any specified year.

My code works fine, but I am having a bit of confusion with my book I am following. It tells me not to implement the two getter methods at the bottom of my first code link because I "don't need them." As my code stands, I definitely need them. Is there something I am missing involving that?

Additionally, it lists the "Easter Class Public Interface" that I am recommended to use as:

calculateEaster(int aYear): String

"The UML method syntax indicates the method takes an integer parameter and returns a string." I do not understand this comment, and consequently, I don't understand how to edit my code in order to follow these guidelines.

If anyone can offer any clarity on the dilemma/question I would be greatly appreciative!

Code:
/**
 * 
 * @author b_t
 *
 */

class Easter {

```
/**
 * @param n is the month
 * @param p is the day
 */
private int n;
private int p;

// Comments via Cay Horstmann's "Big Java" 4th ed. on page 169; p.4.19

// Let y be the year (such as 1800 or 2001).

/**
 * 
 * @param y this will hold the year that users enter
 */
Easter(int y) {

    // Divide y by 19 and call the remainder a. Ignore the quotient.
    int a = y % 19;

    // Divide y by 100 to get a quotient b and a remainder c.
    int b = y / 100;
    int c = y % 100;

    // Divide b by 4 to get a quotient d and a remainder e.
    int d = b / 4;
    int e = b % 4;

    // Divide 8 * b + 13 by 25 to get a quotient g. Ignore the remainder.
    int g = (8 * b + 13) / 25;

    // Divide 19 * a + b - d - g + 15 by 30 to get a remainder h. Ignore the quotient.
    int h = (19 * a + b - d - g + 15) % 30;

    // Divide c by 4 to get a quotient j and a remainder k.
    int j = c / 4;
    int k = c % 4;

    // Divide a + 11 * h by 319 to get a quotient m. Ignore the remainder.
    int m = (a + 11 * h) / 319;

    // Divide 2 * e + 2 * j - k - h + m + 32 by 7 to get a remainder r. Ignore the quotient.
    int r = (2 * e + 2 * j - k - h + m + 32) % 7;

    // Divide h - m + r + 90 by 25 to get a quotient n. Ignore the remainder.
    n = (h - m + r + 90) / 25;

    // Divide h - m + r + n + 19 by 32 to get a remainder p.
    p = (h - m + r + n + 19) % 32;

}
/**
 * 
 * @return n returns the month in which a given year's Easter Sunday will take place
 */
public int getEasterSundayMonth() {

    return n;
}
/**
 * 
 * @return p returns the day in which a given year's Easter Sunday will take place
 */
public int getEasterSundayDay() {

    return p;
}
```

}

AND HERE IS THE TESTER CLASS:

public class EasterTester {

```
public static void main(String[] args)

   {
      Easter myEaster = new Easter(2002);

      System.out.println("In 2002, Easter Sunday is: " + "month = " + myEaster.getEasterSundayMonth() + " and day = " + myEaster.getEasterSundayDay());

      Easter myEaster2 = new Easter(2012);

      System.out.println("In 2012, Easter Sunday is: " + "month = " + myEaster2.getEasterSundayMonth() + " and day = " + myEaster2.getEasterSundayDay());

   }
}
```

Comment: The tester class does not _test_ anything.

Comment: @TrueSoft I thought it tests the years 2002 and 2012? What do you mean by this comment?

Comment: A tester class should test if the results are equal to the expected ones. See how you can make a [JUnit test](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html) (Also, read about [Test Driven Development](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/tdd.html)). Otherwise you could test like this: `int expectedMonth_2012 = 4; if(myEaster2.getEasterSundayMonth() == expectedMonth_2012) System.out.println("Passed"); else System.err.println("Failed; expected month " + expectedMonth_2012 + ", but returned " + myEaster2.getEasterSundayMonth());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book's use of UML like this:

```
calculateEaster(int aYear): String
```

really *just* means that you'd have a public method like this:

```
public String calculateEaster(int aYear)
```

(The parameter name is horrible, by the way. If the book suggested using a prefix of `a`, `an`, `my` or `the` before names, please ignore it... and potentially get a better book.)

I'd argue that the interface would be much better as (in Java syntax)

```
public LocalDate calculateEaster(int year)
```

... using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net)'s `LocalDate` class. If you don't want to use that, make it return a `java.util.Calendar` or potentially a `java.util.Date`. (Neither of those classes really mean what their name implies, and neither is ideal, but there we go...)

... rather than returning a `String` as the book is recommending. However, it's fundamentally a difference in terms of what an *instance* of the object would mean. In your case, it represents a day in the year (although it doesn't remember *which* year, which is odd). The book's recommendation is that there shouldn't be *any* instance state - you'd be building an `EasterCalculator` rather than representing a single instance of Easter.

As an aside, this code is bad:

```
/**
 * @param n is the month
 * @param p is the day
 */
 private int n;
 private int p;
```

Your Javadoc comment is trying to document a single *field* as if it were a *method* with two parameters. For valid Javadoc, you'd want:

```
/** The month of the year */
private int n;

/** The day of the month */
private int p;
```

However, the fact that the fields *need* documenting is indicative that they're badly named. Why don't you just call them `month` and `day` instead?

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I now understand the use of javadoc better; thank you very much for that! Also I noticed my code expired on that site so I will host it on here from here out. I agree that the fields are badly named; I was only using the names suggested by my exercise, sorry! Another question, the method:

public String calculateEaster(int aYear)

How does one enter this into the program? I am familiar with implementing methods and classes in general but not a string in itself. Still very confused about where to go from here in order to make my edited code work.

Comment: @dustdustdust: You should ask that as a separate question, with a *lot* more detail. It's not clear what you mean, and it wouldn't be appropriate to go into detail here, when you're really asking a different question.

Comment: "I do not understand this comment, and consequently, I don't understand how to edit my code in order to follow these guidelines." I believe it is the same question. What more detail than the length of code are you implying is absent?

Comment: @dustdustdust: Well I've explained how that comment is translated into a different method signature for you to implement. You write a method with that signature, and implement it. If you don't have any more explanation of what you're missing, I'm afraid I have no more explanation of what to do. If you're a student, it sounds like now would be a good time to go and talk with your supervisor (or whatever).

Comment: I was just stuck on a stupid compiler error. Got it up and running once I changed the Easter constructor and understood the exact purpose of y. SOrry for the frustration. Your answer is best.